# State time-evolution in the Interaction picture

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, time-evolution, s-matrix-theory

What is the Schrödinger-like equation
$$i\frac{d}{dt}|\psi(t)\rangle_I=V_I|\psi(t)\rangle_I$$
telling us for the behavior of the interaction picture state vectors, $|\psi(t)\rangle_I$, at infinity/asymptotic regions in space?

How are those vectors (at infinity) related to the Fock space states?